# Unable to invoke compose screen in Gmail/Yahoomail using selenium

Tags: selenium, gmail, selenium-rc, yahoo-mail

[image]Can some one help me out how can i invoke compose screen in Gmail/Yahoomail using selenium commands.

Tried with the following commands.

```
selenium.click("href=compose link");
selenium.click("name=Compose");
```

Comment: Are you using Selenium-RC? It's better to switch to Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use webdriver and easily can invoke compose mail screen from gmail/yahoo.
See the code below:

`from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    import unittest, time, re, os
    import HTMLTestRunner
    import xlrd`

```
class gmail(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://gmail.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []


    def test_gmail_login(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url +"/")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Email']").clear()
        print "1. enter user name in username text field"
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Email']").send_keys("xxxx")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']").clear()
        print "2.enter password in password text field"
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']").send_keys("xxxx")
        print " 3. Click signIn button. it has redirect to corresponding gmail home page"
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signIn']").click()
        print "click compose mail button"
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':b7']/div/div").click()
        driver.save_screenshot('/compose.png')
        try:
         driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='z0']/div").click()
```

`

Comment: Tried with webdriver too test case failing when trying to invoke compose screen.

Comment: Hi i got the solution use this xpath code : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='z0']/div").click()

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this by using `Selenium IDE`.  Just record the whole scenario in the SIDE and  do the below steps

`1. GoTo Options

 2. Format

 3. Click the Java/ Junit4/ Remote Control option.`

Now you can see the exact Selenium RC code for the scenario you did and copy and paste it in to any IDE and make use of it.

One advisable suggestion, selenium RC is deprecated and there is no further development on RC. The future is on `Selenium WebDriver`. Please incorporate in to WebDriver.

**Edited:**

Try this code:

```
    //Assume driver is initialized properly some where else.
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("UserName");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("Password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    //Add some wait. Use Selenium Implicit wait and Explicit wait.
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("gbi4t")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
```

It may help you.

SIDE Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Hi manigandan format option is disable in current selenium IDE1.10.0, But even i tried the invoking the compose screen usig selenium IDE and am rewritting the code in java, even after that also am unable to invoke compose screen.

Comment: It's look strange for me. I too have the same version of SIDE and i am having the `format` option. Try to re-install the IDE plugin.

Comment: After clicking do you have any options in that format option??

Comment: I attached the screen shot. Take a look.

Comment: Can you send me the link where u have downloaded the selenium IDE, and the firefox version that your using

Answer (score 0):

To invoke Compose screen of Gmail in Selenium-RC using Java as below:

```
selenium.click("//div[text()='COMPOSE']");
```

To invoke Compose screen of Yahoomail in Selenium-RC using Java as below:

```
selenium.click("id=global_compose_top");
```

The following is the Selenium WebDriver Java code for gmail:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='COMPOSE']")).click();
```

The following is the Selenium WebDriver Java code for yahoo mail:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("global_compose_top")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use selenium wrbdriver

http://ngowda.blogspot.in/2014/01/uploading-file-in-e-commerce-site-using.html

here full code of compose a mail in gmail